# Is there a way to get a Service fabric project template for Stateless ASP.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, azure-service-fabric

After installing .net core 2.1 sdk. When I created Service Fabric **Stateless Service** with .net Core it create a project with .net core 2.1. For the same when I create **Stateless Asp.net Core > API** the project created is for .net core 2.0. Is there a way to get the latest template for Stateless ASP.net Core 2.1 fore service fabric?

Comment: did you update to the latest vs\sdk?

Comment: yes VS 15.7.4 an installed dotnet-sdk-2.1.301-win-x64.exe. from command prompt dotnet --version 2.1.301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the latest template for Stateless ASP.net Core 2.1 fore service fabric?

As you mentioned It seems that there is **no** default  .net core 2.1 service fabric template currently.

I also find the similar [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/service-fabric/issues/85) from github.

But we coud migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.0 to 2.1 mannually. I did a demo following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The following is the detail steps:

1.Create a Asp.net core 2.0 stateless service

2.Change the framework from 2.0 to 2.1

[image]

3.Edit the .csproj file with following code

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsServiceFabricServiceProject>True</IsServiceFabricServiceProject>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Kestrel" Version="3.1.301" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

3.Change the startup.cs file following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.1)